# Using Shapefile Converter in Oracle 12c to load Shapefile?

Tags: oracle-spatial

**Update:**
I resolved the service name issue.  At some point I put in the right combo of parameters (or maybe I omitted some) and this message was displayed:
`The following key/value is missing: -s db_sid OR -sn db_service_name`
The `-sn` option isn't in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17896/sdo_shapefile_converter.htm#SPATL1427) as far as I can tell.

In my case, I replace the `-s GDSRV` with `-sn pdborcl`.

```
Now I'm getting all sorts of errors:  
Connecting to Oracle Database using...  
localhost, 1521, null pdborcl, GISD, ********, shapes, tl_2013_us_state, null, 0  
Dropping old table...  
   Table not previously created.  
Creating new table...  
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype  

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Record #1 not converted.  
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Record #2 not converted.  
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

...  

Record #56 not converted.
56 record(s) not converted.
0 record(s) converted.
Done.
```

**Original Question:**

I am attempting to use the shapefile converter in Oracle12c and I'm not having much success and I think it is due to the container database (CDB) vs pluggable database (PDB).  I need to somehow specify my PDB: `pdborcl`

If I provide the SID, I get an invalid username/password....as expected.

`C:\temp>java oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature -h localhost -p 1521 -s GDSRV -u     GISD -d gisd -t shapes -f tl_2013_us_state -r 0 -g geom`

```
host: localhost
port: 1521
sid: GDSRV
db_username: GISD
db_password: ********
db_tablename: shapes
shapefile_name: tl_2013_us_state
SRID: 0
db_geometry_column: geom
Connecting to Oracle Database using...
localhost, 1521, GDSRV null, GISD, ********, shapes, tl_2013_us_state, null, 0
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:938)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:480)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:416)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:825)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:596)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature.main(SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature.java:341)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature.main(SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature.java:345)
```

From SQLPLUS, I would use the PDB name instead to connect and I'm in.  How do you connect to the PDB when calling oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature?

`java oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature -h localhost -p 1521 -s pdborcl -u GISD -d gisd -t shapes -f tl_2013_us_state -r 0 -g geom`

```
host: localhost
port: 1521
sid: pdborcl
db_username: GISD
db_password: ********
db_tablename: shapes
shapefile_name: tl_2013_us_state
SRID: 0
db_geometry_column: geom
Connecting to Oracle Database using...
localhost, 1521, pdborcl null, GISD, ********, shapes, tl_2013_us_state, null, 0
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature.main(SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature.java:341)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:272)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
```

Here's the docs on the 12c converter: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17896/sdo_shapefile_converter.htm#SPATL1427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain Oracle didn't update the docs for 12c.

I'm going to list out a few things that I got hung up on.

1. For a pluggable database, you provide the name as the service name
   with the `-sn` switch.
2. The docs has `ojdbc5.jar` in the class path.  I didn't have this
   file in 12c, but I did have a `ojdbc7.jar` and that works.
3. As for the actual issue that I reference in my question: my database
   was jacked.  A large number of SDO views were broken which caused
   just about anything with SDO to break.  I installed a new database,
   and did some checking...everything was good.

   The only thing I did different in the first database was to execute the `sdoupggeom.sql`
   to increase the size of the ordinate arrays in order to support very
   large geoemtries.

   [A.4 Increasing the Size of Ordinate Arrays to Support Very Large Geometries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17896/sdo_migrat.htm#SPATL1426)

   So it appears that this script did some bad things to my database.

Here's an example of a command that worked in Oracle 12c:

```
C:\temp>java -cp C:\app\orcl\product\12.1.0\dbhomeTest\jdbc\lib\ojdbc7.jar;C:\app\orcl\product\12.1.0\dbhomeTest\md\jlib\sdoutl.jar;C:\app\orcl\product\12.1.0\dbhomeTest\md\jlib\sd
oapi.jar oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature -h localhost -p 1523 -sn pdborclt -u GISD -d gisd -t shapes -f tl_2013_us_state -r 0 -g geom
host: localhost
port: 1523
service_name: pdborclt
db_username: GISD
db_password: ********
db_tablename: shapes
shapefile_name: tl_2013_us_state
SRID: 0
db_geometry_column: geom
Connecting to Oracle Database using...
localhost, 1523, null pdborclt, GISD, ********, shapes, tl_2013_us_state, null, 0
Dropping old table...
   Table not previously created.
Creating new table...
Converting record #10 of 56
Converting record #20 of 56
Converting record #30 of 56
Converting record #40 of 56
Converting record #50 of 56
56 record(s) converted.
Done.
```

Comment: Can you confirm this: (1) you ran the load successfully on 12c. (2) you enlarged the geometry type (3) you ran the exact same load again on the same database, and now it fails ? If this is true then there is some sort of incompatibility with the enlarged geometries and 12c. Please report that as a bug to Oracle. Make sure to provide a reproducible example.