# Loading shapefile in Oracle Spatial?

Tags: shapefile, oracle-spatial

I am new to oracle spatial. I want to load shapefile into oracle spatial. I am using oracle 11g. I have already look at the following examples and answers

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_shapefile_converter.htm#SPATL1430
```

[How do use the Shapefile Converter in Oracle 12c to load a Shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76681/how-do-use-the-shapefile-converter-in-oracle-12c-to-load-a-shapefile)

Where I found the following example to load a shapefile

> java -classpath
>   %ORACLE_HOME%\jdbc\lib\ojdbc5.jar;%ORACLE_HOME%\md\jlib\sdoutl.jar;%OR
>   ACLE_HOME%\md\jlib\sdoapi.jar
>   oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature - h gis01 -p 1521 -s
>   orcl -u scott -d tiger -t states -f states -r 8307 -g geom

I have the files on the following directory

`ojdbc14.jar - D:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib`

`ojdbc5.jar - D:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib`

`sdoutl.jar -D:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib`

`sdoapi.jar - D:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib`

Java - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin

`shapefile (bd.shp) - E:\data\bd.shp`

So I used the following codes

`java -classpath D:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc5.jar;D:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\sdoutl.jar;D:\app\user\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\jdbc\lib\sdoapi.jar oracle.spatial.util.SampleShapefileToJGeomFeature -h localhost -p 1521 -s hr -u hr -d password -t bd -f E:\data\bd -r 8307 -g geom`

Would anyone help me to run this code with those directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simlest tool for loading shapefile into oracle spatial database is provided by Oracle itself as [Mapbuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/mapviewer/downloads/index-100641.html). You can download it from Oracle site. You need to register (free) once with Oracle.

You need to connect to your database where you want to save the shapefile and choose the Import Shapefile as option as shown below:

[image]

Then you need to browse and select the shapefile.

Select whether you want to create a new table or update an existing one (You need to have the same attribute columns for this).

You can also choose the name of geometry column.

You will have the option to import single shapefile or multiple.

The image below describes the options available while importing the shapefile:

[image]

Set the SRID and indexing as below:

[image]

You can also choose any (optional) predefined theme (styling for your shapefile) as below:

[image]

Then click Next and Finish to complete the loading.

[image]

That's it.

Comment: I'm following that link, it appears to go here (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/mapviewer/downloads/index-100641.html) and what I just downloaded doesn't seem to be at all what your screenshots contain, I've got a mapbuilder that runs on localhost:8080. Is there something different to download?

Comment: You need to download mapbuilder which is a jar file (not mapviewer which runs on web server).

Comment: Ah, now I see it, sorry, I didn't realize that unlike other areas of the oracle site, there are multiple program downloads in each section. Thanks!

Comment: You can download mapviewer also. It's a good application to display rasters, vectors and run spatial queries on web page. Tutorial is also given in the same application package

Answer (score 4):

Rather than use the Oracle tools (which if they're anything like anything Oracle I've ever seen are a completely mess), you could try using [OGR2OGR](http://www.gdal.org/drv_oci.html) - There is a GUI app for it too - http://www.ogr2gui.ca/en/screenshot.php

Hopefully that'll do what you want and be simpler as well.

Comment: Thank you but Its not connecting with  Oracle Database

Answer (score 2):

I used the **["Spatial Data Manager"](http://www.mapet.altervista.org)**, another graphical tool to load shapefiles and file geodatabases in Oracle and other spatial db.
http://www.mapet.altervista.org

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me what will be the instance for oracle DB connection?

Comment: instance is the alias in your tnsnanes.ora