# Load large amount of data to an ArcGIS Enterprise Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-enterprise

I have a large amount of geospatial data stored within a File Geodatabase, currently, the GDB is 58 GB. I need to load this data into an Oracle Enterprise database. Considering that the Append tool in ArcGIS doesn't perform very well, what would be the fastest way to load this data? In my research, I came across SQL Loader, but I'm concerned about potential issues with geometry data types.

Comment: You can consider giving a try to FME Form www.safe.com . Also check out this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81546/loading-shapefile-in-oracle-spatial

Comment: A 58GiB FGDB isn't all that large. Oracle CLOBs are slow, though, and it will likely be much larger in SDO_GEOMETRY, if you go that route. Unfortunately, this is just soliciting opinions; while that may be okay in [Chat], it's not okay in the main Q&A site.

Comment: Unfortunately looks like i need 20 points of reputation to use this chat.

Comment: Do you mention append because you're adding data from one class to another? If you're making new data sets, just run Copy. Maybe I'm being blasé, but start it on Friday and come back in Monday morning and hopefully its done.